# Keep the axis labels order same even after filtering (PowerBI)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have this visual where it is currently sorted like this:
[image]

This already has a visual filter which is like {Status = 'Success'}

After using slicers, the y axis label (ApplicationName) are getting sorted as per the new highest machine count. I want the labels to stay intact as per the original count even after applying different filters (using slicers). How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to apply a sort order at a "default context". Then, when context changes by filtering and slicing, this default should still be used for sort order.

In that case, you could create a calculated column, which is calculated from the machine count in your default context.

When you change context while browsing the report, the default context will still be used for sorting.